# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSString *' from 'Staff *__strong'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting this warning on the second line shown here. The cells of a `UITableView` are being populate from the *self.staffNames* which is of a `NSDictionaryResultType`. *Observations* is my `NSManagedObject`

```
Staff *currentList = [[self.staffNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"staffName"];
cell.textLabel.text = currentList;
```

Everything works as I want it to but I would like to remove the warning. Any ideas?

Comment: You left off **only the essential part** of the error message...

Comment: I have edited it. Being new to this etc I am not sure which parts are most important. Nevertheless thanks for this pointing out - I will know for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *currentList = [[self.staffNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"staffName"];

cell.textLabel.text = currentList;
```

Comment: -1 `valueForKey:` should not be used unless you know what you are doing. Also using a modern indexed/keyed access is preferable

Comment: In NSDictionary objectForKey: is collection of objects where valueForKey: is a single object.So if you want to fetch NSString (which is a single object not a array) then you should always use valueForKey: instead of objectForKey:

Comment: @AnandK: That is not correct. `objectForKey:` returns the value associated with a given key. `valueForKey:` is a Key-Value Coding method. Both do the same for a "simple" key, but work very different for a "key path" like "a.b.c".

Answer (score 2):

Unless `Staff` is a subclass of `NSString` (which I wouldn't recommend), you need to set your label text to a property on `Staff` that represents what you want to display.

For example:

```
cell.textLabel.text = currentList.text;
```